# event.target undefinied, sometimes, in React handleChange function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

EDIT: Problem was solved, thank you to Pedro Mutter for making me realise my mistake. The icon in the button appeared as a seperate component and created the problem. I was able to find the difference between clicking the button and clicking the icon thanks to Pedro Mutters comment.

I'm trying to create a visual interface for a camera control module and when I try to access `event.target.value` in the following code it works sometimes but doesn't work most of the time.

`this.props.updateState()` is a function used to update the backend.

I'm looking for a solution that would eliminate all instances of undefined being returned.

**Ps:**
I have tried to use

```
onClick={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
```

but it made no difference.

Here is a reduced version of my component:

```
class PlaceHolderName extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  state = {};

  handleChange = event => {
    this.props.updateState(this.props.componentID, event.target.value + "");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Paper style={{ width: "200px", padding: "5px", height: "320px" }}>
        <p style={{ fontFamily: "sans-serif", textAlign: "center" }}>
          {this.props.displayname}
        </p>
        <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
          <button
            className={"camera-control-button"}
            onClick={this.handleChange}
            value="up"
          >
            {this.upArrow}
          </button>
        </div>
      </Paper>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(PlaceHolderName);
```

Comment: What is `undefined`? The `event` or `event.target` or `event.target.value`? Could you `console.log` it and post here, please?

Answer (score 0):

I would bind your functions used within the screen within the constructor. You can then call them like: `onClick={this.yourfunction}`

```
...
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);   //<-- Bind in the constructor
  }

  state = {};

  handleChange(event) {
    this.props.updateState(this.props.componentID, event.target.value + "");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      ...
          <button
            className={"camera-control-button"}
            onClick={this.handleChange}
            value="up"
          >
      ...
    );
  }
...
```

more info here: https://medium.com/shoutem/react-to-bind-or-not-to-bind-7bf58327e22a